# Finding whether $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\rm dt}{\sqrt{1-x\cos^2{t}}}$ is increasing or decreasing

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality, definite-integrals

I'm trying to find if$$f(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\rm dt}{\sqrt{1-x\cos^2{t}}}\;,\;\text{where}\; x \in (0,1)$$ is increasing or decreasing.

**My Attempt:**

Using DUIS to find $f'(x)$, We get$$f'(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\cos^2t\;\rm dt}{{2(1-x\cos^2{t})}^{3/2}}$$
How to proceed further?

Comment: If $f(t) > 0$ for all $a < t < b,$ then what can be said about $\int_a^b f(t) dt$?

Comment: @StephenDonovan: I get your point, Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to differentiate. $\sqrt {1-x\cos^{2}t}$ is  decreasing function of $x$ so $\frac 1 {\sqrt {1-x\cos^{2}t}}$ is increasing which makes its integral also increasing.